# F# Factorial function using while loop

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, f#, factorial

i have gotten an assignment requesting the following:

*Write a function
sum : n:int -> int
which uses the counter value, a local mutable value s, and a while-loop to compute the
sum 1+2+···+n as (2). If the function is called with any value smaller than 1, then it is
to return the value 0.*

Now i know that you can make a recursive factorial script using match, but i can't quite put my finger as to how you can do the same using a while loop.

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Can you post a snippet of how you would do it recursively? That will help us provide you with a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sums up the first `n` integers (that's not a factorial function!):

```
let sum n = 
    let mutable s = 0
    let mutable counter = n
    while counter > 0 do
        s <- s + counter
        counter <- counter - 1
    s
```

For comparison, the tail-recursive version:

```
let sumRec n = 
    let rec sumRecInner n accu = 
        if (n <= 0) then accu else
            sumRecInner (n - 1) (n + accu)
    sumRecInner n 0
```

Answer (score 3):

As this is an assignment question, I'm not going to answer by just giving the solution, but I think it will help you to see a brief snippet that shows all the constructs that you need to combine:

```
let imperativeDemo y = // Define a function taking 'y' as an argument
  let mutable x = y    // Create a mutable variable 'x' initialized to 'y'
  while x < 20 do      // Loop while 'x' is less than 20
    x <- x + 1         // Mutate 'x' - increment it by one
  x                    // Return the final value of 'x'
```

This function does not do anything *useful*, but it should be easy to adapt to implement the logic necessary for a factorial function.